# Text on canvas not clickable

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't seem to find anything on this. There are a few answers regarding buttons and images but this is only text so it doesn't quite help.

I have a canvas in my scene which contains gameObjects that have a text component a boxCollider2D and a script that has OnMouseDown() implemented. I can't seem to click the texts though. If I switch to scene view I don't even see the text or its collider.

What do I need to add to make Unity regonise clicking on the text?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure box collider will work on UI elements. The reason you don't see it in your scene is the text is in UI space on a Canvas. You're better off either adding a button component to a parent, setting its color to transparent and childing the text, using a Graphics Raycast or IPointer events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following TEEBQNE's comment, you need to to use other methods if your objects are on a canvas, OnMouseDown() will not work.

You can use the following interface

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (eventData.pointerId == -1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Text clicked on canvas");
        }
    }

}
```

Otherwise, if you want, you can also create a 3d Text Object, as opposed to the canvas element, which does work with OnMouseDown()

[image: Menu]

Keep in mind this needs to have a collider, it is best if you parent the text itself to an object with the collider

[image: text object]

This will then be able to call

```c#
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    Debug.Log("Text clicked in world");
}
```